# AR-Speeker: raw cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: r.java-file

I am using the **AR-Speeker** [project](https://github.com/nmatsui/AR_Speeker)

And I am facing the following error: `raw cannot be resolved or is not a field`

In the file: `AR_SpeekerActivity.java`, in the following 2 lines:

```
players.add(new Player("Porl.obj", "Porl.patt", 3.0f, R.raw.porl_01));
players.add(new Player("Elaine.obj", "Elaine.patt", 3.0f, R.raw.elaine_01));
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because in that project there is no raw folder in the res folder. Try to add the raw folder inside res folder and also add 2 mp3 files in the raw folder but change the name to `porl_01.mp3` and `elaine_01.mp3`. Finally clean the project, this may solve the problem.